# ffmpeg - get green overlay instead of red when using multiply?

Tags: ffmpeg, filter

multiply should result in a darker image according to [this website](https://www.cairographics.org/operators/). However every `multiply` options with input that I'm using resulted in darker **green** videos instead of layering it with colour that I use for layering.

Many people refer that as format issue and resolved by using `format=rgba` options, however in my case there I'm still stuck.

FFMPEG command :

```
ffmpeg -i red.jpg -i car.mp4 -y -filter_complex [0][1]scale2ref[a][b];[a]setdar=1/1[c];[b]setdar=1/1[d];[c][d]blend=all_mode=multiply:all_opacity=1[out];[out]eq=contrast=2:brightness=0.5[ckv] -map [ckv] output.mp4
```

with `format=rgba`

```
ffmpeg -i red.jpg -i car.mp4 -y -filter_complex [0][1]scale2ref[a][b];[a]setdar=1/1[c];[b]setdar=1/1,format=rgba[d];[c][d]blend=all_mode=multiply:all_opacity=1[out];[out]eq=contrast=2:brightness=0.5[ckv] -map [ckv] output.mp4
```

assets in case someone want to try it.
- [Images](https://i.ibb.co/smSGGwW/red.jpg)
- [Videos](https://www.pexels.com/video/car-driving-along-the-dessert-highway-1572342/)

FFMPEG version 4.1

Comment: Do you want to overlay a red tint on the video?

Comment: Yes exacly. I want to overlay it with blend mode multiply,

Comment: If you want a tint, don't use mode multiply, use mode overlay.

Comment: Shame on me, I just wanna try to replicate photoshop effect with multiply, so multiply on photoshop doesn't have the same effect in FFmpeg? HTML Canvas behave same like photoshop does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is wrong, if you enable debug log messages, you would notice that yuv formats are still being used.
You need to put `format=rgba` filter to all inputs and outputs of blend filter to make it work as you want.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to FFmpeg, I tried as you said but the video isn't playable. `ffmpeg -i red.jpg -i car.mp4 -y -filter_complex [0][1]scale2ref[a][b];[a]setdar=1/1,format=rgba[c];[b]setdar=1/1,format=rgba[d];[c][d]blend=all_mode=multiply:all_opacity=1[out];[out]eq=contrast=2:brightness=0.5,format=rgba[ckv] -map [ckv] output.mp4`

Comment: `ffmpeg -i .\car.mp4 -filter_complex "format=rgba" output3.mp4 -loglevel debug` Even i tried this the video arent playable, and still resulting on `yuv` If I'm not mistaken the `yuv` is `coded y,u,v intra: 53.8% 1.8% 1.7% inter: 19.1% 0.5% 0.5%` on the end of conversion right?

Comment: If you set format as rgba, then ffmpeg will convert to yuv444p for the sake of x264. Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` as well.

Comment: thanks @Gyan and @Paul, got it working with blend modes multiply `ffmpeg -i .\red.jpg -i .\car.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]scale2ref[a][b];[a]setdar=16/9,format=rgba[c];[b]setdar=16/9,format=rgba[d];[c][d]blend=all_mode=multiply:all_opacity=1,format=rgba[out];[out]eq=contrast=2:brightness=0.5[ckv]" -map "[ckv]" -pix_fmt yuv420p output3.mp4`

Comment: So this is happening if using an image with one colour only. when using coloured images. Everything fine. should be noted thanks.